# scrapy : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'am beginner on scrapy. I am trying to iterate ads but I get this error.

I don't know what is wrong in my code.

Here is what I did:

```
     class ScrapAiaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'scrap_aia'
        allowed_domains = ['aia-immobilier.fr']
        start_urls = ['http://aia-immobilier.fr/fr/ventes']
                    
     def parse(self, response):
        ads = response.xpath('//li[@class="property initial"]').getall(),
        for ad in ads:
            yield {
                'type': ad.xpath('./div[@class="titles"]/h2/text()').get(),
                'price': ad.xpath('./li[@class="price"]/div/text()').get(),
                'room': ad.xpath('./li[@class="room"]/div/text()').get(),
                'area': ad.xpath('./li[@class="area"]/div/text()').get()
            }
```

When I run this code, I get an error which explain that list does not have Xpath attribute. Thus I don't understand how I can iterate and get some items for each ad in the list.

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 132, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
     File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 354, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
    File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 354, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 342, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 40, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 66, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\kgonc\Desktop\Projets\scrap_immo\aia-immobilier.fr\scrap_immo\spiders\scrap_aia.py", line 18, in parse
    'type': ad.xpath('./div[@class="titles"]/h2/text()').get(),
     AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ads = response.xpath('//li[@class="property initial"]')
    for ad in ads:
        yield {
            'type': ad.xpath('.//div[@class="titles"]/h2/text()').get(),
            'price': ad.xpath('.//li[@class="price"]/div/text()').get(),
            'room': ad.xpath('.//li[@class="room"]/div/text()').get(),
            'area': ad.xpath('.//li[@class="area"]/div/text()').get()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug `response.xpath('//li[@class="property initial"]').getall()` and see what's returning, because you should use something like this: `response.xpath('.//div/ul[@class="_list listing"]').extract()`. Change until you get all items.